App Check debug provider on Apple platforms
I use xcode very rarely and maybe this is a stupid question, but where do I put the code when the firebase instructions say "In your debug build"
The code:
let providerFactory = AppCheckDebugProviderFactory()
AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
            
FirebaseApp.configure()

I want to generate a firebase app-check debug token
link firebase instruction: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider
instructions: In your debug build, before using any Firebase backend services,
create and set the App Check debug provider factory

I think you can put them inside the AppDelegate in this method below:
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) {
        let providerFactory = AppCheckDebugProviderFactory()
        AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
                    
        FirebaseApp.configure()
}

